# How to retrieve data fields in a table for a drop down menu in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I hope I can get assistance from here. A very amateur to Laravel.

Here is my code. I am trying to create a drop down select menu and the data should be from the database from another table which is actually connected using a foreign key only.

```
         <div class="form-group">
         {{ Form::select('size', array('a' => '', 'b' => ''), null,array('class'=>'form-control','style'=>'','placeholder' => 'Select Activity   Category:','required' )) }}</div>


         public function createPackage()
{
    $package = chap_activity_package::all();
    return view ('Chap_activity_packages.chap_activity_package',  compact('chap_activity_packages'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-pluck) method which will generate list of properties for you, like:

```
$data = chap_activity_package::pluck('name', 'id');
```

Then use this data in `Form::select`:

```
{!! Form::select('size', $data, null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'style' => '', 'placeholder' => 'Select Activity Category:', 'required' )) !!}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Alexey. I will try this now. Thank you!!

Comment: I guess I am not really sure how to put my problems in words. :( I am trying to create a drop down select menu ..It did not went thru maybe I was wrong on my coding.

Comment: `Form::select` is creating dropdown menu. `pluck()` gets data for it. You can see what data do you get with inserting `dd($data);` clause right after `$data = ...`.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you for your answer. The thing here is that I need to get the data from 'activity_category' table for the drop down menu so that when I hit 'add package' button, the table for 'activity_category_package' will include an id where it indicates the type of activity category this package belongs to.,

Comment: I already have a table for activity category named 'chap_activity_categories' and each activity category has a lot of activity_packages..

Comment: Mezenichap_activity_categories table
*id
*chap_activity_categories_name
*created at
*updated at

chap_activity_packages table
*id
*chap_activity_package_code
*chap_activity_packages_name
*chap_activity_package_price
*chap_activity_categories_id (which is a foreign key in reference to the categories table)

I added successfully activitty categories already using form, then I need to add activity packages using a form too..